# writing alias to bashrc file using echo command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alias

Is it possible to write an "alias to .bashrc" file using echo command in Terminal to make the alias permanent?.

i.e. `echo "alias $NAME='$DEFINTION'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is. only bash'es launched after writing the file will be affected. to have the alias defined in your current bash session, you need to run `alias $NAME='$DEFINTION'` in that session before/after adding it to the bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you should also make sure that your login shell would also load it as login shells don't read `.bashrc`. Only interactive shells that are summoned without the `-l` option reads it.

A way to do this is to have this line in your `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```